# toast that outlive activity

Tags: android, android-toast

I'm showing a toast (for debugging) when my app exit (or crashes). The toast will not be immediately closed because the activity is finished (or killed). Is there a way to show a toast after the activity is not valid anymore.

I'm using cocos2dx, I tried a couple of toast methods, they all close

I'm cocos2dx framework. In my AppActivity, I tried many methods

e.g In AppActivity.java

```
public static void ShowToast(final String toastMessage){
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Toast.makeText(activity_, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code? `Toast` will not destroy when the activity is finishing.

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi, edited with code sample

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- using instead of  `Activity's` context, use `Application's` context
- You can set [setDuration](http://%20%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setDuration(int)) of Toast and [cancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#cancel()) by yourself

  But it depends how you use `Toast`.

Comment: No difference, if my app crash, the toast gets closed immediately